# PHP Session Security And "Remember Me"

Tags: php, session, cookies

I've been reading about sessions in order to make a safe login system. As I understand, sessions are very unlikely to be stolen through brute-force even though it is not impossible since they use only a cookie to match the session to a computer.

I was thinking about implementing a second check in order to make it impossible for a hacker to brute-force their way into somebody else's session, the idea is to also set a random cookie and check if it matches to the session data stored in the server, I guess it could possibly make it n² harder to get a right match.

Sample code:

```
//if login is successful 
if(password($this->checkPass,$this->time) == $this->pass){
    $random = hash("sha256",rand(0,getrandmax()).$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
    session_start();
    session_regenerate_id(1);
    $_SESSION['name'] = $this->loginData;
    $_SESSION['logged'] = 1;
    $_SESSION['cookie'] = $random;
    setcookie("data",$random,0,"/");
}

//Sample code to authenticate a user:
//it checks if the user is logged in and if the user's cookie is what it is
//supposed to be, otherwise kills the session in the server

if($_SESSION['logged'] != 1 || $_SESSION['cookie'] != $_COOKIE['data']){
    $_SESSION = array();
    session_destroy();
    setcookie("data","",time()-3600);
    header("Location: $adminLogInPage");
    die;
}
```

Would it be a good trade-off between security and performance? Or is it completely unnecessary?

I was thinking about implementing similar code for a "Remember me" feature, but I wouldn't use a session, just a triple cookie system. One cookie to match the user and the other two to match random values stored on a database. Is it a good idea?

Considering the website is using SSL, is there any threat that isn't being avoided?

Comment: why would you create a 2nd cookie and not store your random hash with the id in one cookie?

Comment: I think brute forcing a session takes years, but you could take another hash algorithm to make it even more difficult. [session.configuration](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php).

Comment: For *remeber me* use `cookie` and for *secure session* use `tokens`.

Comment: @Dagon because if somebody happens to find a valid cookie value through brute-force, the second cookie would invalidate the session, the same with the third. But I don't if it is a good idea, I guess it depends on how random the cookie value really is. I would like to know if it will make a difference performance-wise.

Comment: For "remember me", why not just bump up the length of time the session cookie lasts?